# declaring and initialising a vector in the header file

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, header-files, stdvector

In my entry cpp file the following works.

```
include <vector>
#define ROWS 10
#define COLS 20

std::vector<std::vector<int>> exampleVector (ROWS, std::vector<int>(COLS, 10));
```

However if I put that same code in my example.h file I get

- "expected a type specifier" on ROWS
- "expected a ')'" on COLS
- "expected a type specifier" on 10
- "expected a ';' on the second )

I'm aware I could just put

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> exampleVector;
```

in my example.h file and

```
exampleVector.resize(ROWS, std::vector<int>(COLS, 10));
```

in my example.cpp file.

However for cleanliness of code I would like it in my header file along with my fixed arrays.

```
char exampleName[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]
int exampleConfig[MAX_LEVELS]
```

etc

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's something wrong with your sample code (closing `>` missing?) but ignoring that, the answer is: **the size of a `std::vector` cannot be specified at definition time**.

On the other hand, the size of a `std::array` can be:

```
#include <array>

#define ROWS 10
#define COLS 20

std::array<std::array<int, ROWS>, COLS> exampleArray;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much

Comment: Apologies @Sam Dean , I've probably answered the wrong question. This does nothing to address the header/source file problem, so be aware that this might be a red herring.

Comment: It couldn't be more wrong. What `vector(size_type, T)` constructor of `vector<T>` does?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Revolver_Ocelot - `vector(size_type, T)`, being a constructor, cannot be used in a static definition. On the other hand, `array<T, size_type>`, being a type, can be used in a static definition.

Comment: Example of using said constructor to declare a vector with static storage duration without problems: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5025f7fc69972824

Comment: Oh yes! I've got all tied up. The OP talks about including a header, so I had a vague notion of this: `class C { std::vector<int> v(5); std::array<int, 5> a; };`. In that case the vector constructor is invalid while the array definition is okay. Mea culpa on the bad description.